# imagemagick multi layer tiff

Tags: imagemagick, tiff

Hi i have a standard tif file and I want to create a multi layered tiff.

I can seem to find anything on how to do it on the internet.

can you help please.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want a layered tif from one source image? Or do you have multiple source images you want to place into one layered tif (with each image as a layer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
convert [source image] -define tiff:tile-geometry=256x256 -compress jpeg 'ptif:o.tif'
```

This will create a layered tif from the source and name it o.tif using imagemagick